# IndexError: list index out of range (bimbam.py)

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, decompiling

So I wanted to decompile a game using:

> Python 2.7.15, Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Package for Python 2.7, Cython 0.21.2 and the anaconda-master package.

I'm doing this on Windows 8.1 Build 9600 just so you know.

I followed this guide: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lK_DDFpvlFw) But at 20:56 I get an error of bimbam.py (the tool to decompile the game). I reinstalled everything, used different versions, changed directories, followed other guides and used older anaconda-master packages but I can't get rid of the error. I think I know what the error means: "there is nothing in the place where something should be" or  "the script wants to access a variable/path which doesn't exist".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\AnacondaDecompiler-master\tools\bimbam.py", lin
e 72, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\AnacondaDecompiler-master\tools\bimbam.py", lin
e 38, in main
    input = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to configure an argument that your program will use. 
`input = sys.argv[1]` caused the index error meaning that there is no argument passed.

Can you run the program with a matching argument? 
in example `python bimbam.py <filename>`

Comment: The syntax of the programm is,what I know: bimbam.py "path\of\the\game\exe" "path\of\the\output\foulder

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed the probleme, as you said "python bimbam.py " I tried >> python bimbam.py "path\of\the\game\exe" "path\of\the\output\foulder" and it goes. I don't know why, but now I'm happy that my morning wasn't for free! ... By the way, how dumb to answer my own question.